# Rsync Job for Synchronising Two HDs is Filling Up the / Partition

Tags: mount, rsync

I have two additional HDs mounted at /media/hd1 and /media/hd2. I created a cron rsync job to copy all files from hd1 to hd2. This runs every night.

The last couple of nights I noticed that the / partition was full and after investigating, I found that the /media/hd2 was actually a directory on my primary hard disk (i.e. /), not the additional /media/hd2 hard disk.

Here is the rsync command:

```
rsync -azp --stats /media/hd1/ /media/hd2/
```

Is it possible that hd2 was put to sleep by the power management feature, and that rsync just went ahead and created this as a folder in /media?

Comment: Please post your `rsync` command, maybe related to no-trailing slash on destination or something related?.

Comment: Thanks, I added the rsync command to the original question.

Comment: It is possible that the disk got unmounted. You should look at `dmesg` or your logs to see why it got unmounted. You could use `autofs`. autofs is a program for automatically mounting directories on an as-needed basis. [autofs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs)